# Set circumference as boundary for loop-ed line in P5.js

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I am trying to limit the height of the looped lines to the boundary/circumference of a circle()

I couldn't find any solution to solve the issue...

```js
let numCols = 10
let margin = 100
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  test = circle(100,100,100);
  for (let i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
    let iMapped = map(i, 0, numCols - 1, 50, 150);
    line(iMapped, 100, iMapped, 200);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Define the center and the radius of the circle:

```js
let centerx = 100;
let centery = 100;
let radius = 50;
```

Compute the angle from the center to circle dependent on the x coordinate by [`acos`](https://processing.org/reference/acos_.html) and the y distance by [`sin`](https://processing.org/reference/sin_.html):

```js
let x = iMapped - centerx;
let angle = acos(x/50);
line(iMapped, centery, iMapped, centery + 50 * sin(angle));
```

See the example:

```js
let numCols = 10
let margin = 100
function setup() {
     createCanvas(400, 400);
} 

function draw() {
    background(220);

    let centerx = 100;
    let centery = 100;
    let radius = 50; 
    test = circle(centerx, centery, radius*2);
    
    for (let i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
        let iMapped = map(i, 0, numCols - 1, 50, 150);
        let x = iMapped - centerx;
        let angle = acos(x/50);
        line(iMapped, centery, iMapped, centery + 50 * sin(angle));
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```